# Can a non-zero element of $M_n(\Bbb{C})$ be nilpotent?

Tags: matrices

> Let $A\in M_2(\Bbb{C})$. If $A$ is nilpotent, then $A^2=0$.

If $A\in M(\Bbb{C})$, then $AA^*=I$, where $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$. How can a non-zero element of $M_2(\Bbb{C})$ ever be nilpotent? For example, let $A^2=0$. However, $A^2(A^*)^2=I$, which is not possible if $A^2$ is zero!

Comment: How about the matrix whose top right term is $1$ and other terms are $0$?

Comment: Where did you take from that $\;A\in M(\Bbb C)\implies AA^*=I\;$ ? This is false.

Comment: @Timbuc- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnitaryMatrix.html

Comment: @algebraically_speaking Yes, unitary matrices...but why do you think **all** complex (square) matrices are unitary?!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the linear application defined via its values on a basis $\{x,y\}$:
$$
A(x ) = y
\\
A(y)  =0
$$

It is nilpotent but it is not zero.

---

To prove that if $A$ is nlpotent then $A^2=0$, consider an integer $p$ such as there is an element $x\neq 0$, such as $A(x)^p\neq 0$. Then, prove that
$$
(x,A(x), \dots ,A^p(x))
$$is a basis of the current space.